# ¿Cómo obtener un input y transformarlo en un array, para luego devolverlo al mismo input transformado?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

como puedo obtener el valor de un input, almacenarlo y luego devolverlo al mismo input en forma de array?. Actualmente obtengo el valor del input, pero cuando intento transformarlo a un array vuelve como string nuevamente.

```
obs:any;
observation=[];
transformObservation(){

  this.obs=this.professionalForm.get('observations').value.split(" ") //aquí obtengo el input e intento pasarlo a array



  console.log(this.observation);
}

//Acá esta el Input
<ion-card  class="ion-padding">
    <ion-input formControlName="observations" #observation (ionChange)="transformObservation()">Añadir una observación:</ion-input>
  </ion-card>
```

La consola al escribir me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a la hora de mandar la petición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debería mostrarme ["TEST"]

Gracias!

Comment: Realiza la conversión antes de enviar la petición. Mientras estés usando el input manéjalo como una cadena.

Comment: En teoría el ionChange esta escuchando una función que se encarga de transformar el valor del input a Array al modificar dicho input. Aún no me queda del todo claro como hacer la transformación, si consigo darle solución dejaré la respuesta. ¿Alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: No queda clara la intención. La cadena convertida en arreglo se guarda en `obs` ¿y después?

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar guardando el valor en otra variable y llamando a un ngModel para establecer el input con ese valor. Funciona, me ejecuta el request de manera  correcta, pero por consola arroja este error: TypeError: this.obs.split is not a function. Funcionalmente no afecta al parecer, lo solucione usando .toString(), pero ahora me genero un loop infinito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente di con la solución

1. Se crean 2 variables, pueden ser de tipo any (obs y observation)
2. En obs guardamos el valor del campo del input mediante el nombre del formGroup utilizando get y entre parentesis va el formControl asociado al input.
3. en la variable observation almacenamos el valor de obs y lo pasamos a array con la función split().
4. En vez de (ionChange) utilizamos solo (change), al parecer en ciertos casos se genera un bug que hace un loop infinito.
5. Utilizamos ngModel y le asignamos observation para definir el input con el valor ya transformado en array.

```
transformObservation(){
 this.obs=this.professionalForm.get('observations').value;
 this.observation=this.obs.split();
}
```

```
<ion-input formControlName="observations" type="text" #obs (change)="transformObservation()" [(ngModel)]="observation">Añadir una observación:</ion-input>
```